# block input when length exceeds his limit

Tags: validation, textfield, vaadin

I have a question concerning the TextField of Vaadin. I want to block input when he reaches the maxLength of let's say 20 chars... How Can I do this? I already tried to set it immediate with validation but that only works when you do an isValid()...

Can anyone help me? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Textfield.setMaxLength(int maxLength)` method to set the maximum number of characters for your textfield.

For example, using the methode above with 3 as paramater, will bloc the user to insert a four (and more) character.

Regards.

Éric.

Comment: You might experience this issue also in Vaadin 7 - http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/9940